# How to edit autocomplete suggestion list using Jquery autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am created a demo of autocomplete using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
plugin. 
Now the suggested list which appears on pressing key is

```
<ul>
    <li>
          Suggestion
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I have to edit the list like :

```
<ul>
    <li>
           <a>Suggestion</a>
          <br />
        <a>data1</a><a>data2</a>
    </li>

   </ul>
```

how can I do this? I seen script for autocomplete but not found any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the autocomplete with the formatItem, and the parse properties of the configuration object.

This question has been answered here:
[JQuery AutoComplete results format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529652/jquery-autocomplete-results-format)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to add some HTML to the result. If that is correct, the [jquery ui docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) point to a resource (at the bottom of the docs page):

> The label is always treated as text, if you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js). The demos all focus on different variations of the source-option - look for the one that matches your use case, and take a look at the code.

Or, you can add custom data using the open event of the autocomplete. See example here:

http://www.jensbits.com/2011/03/03/jquery-autocomplete-with-html-in-dropdown-selection-menu/